# How to stop multi trigger of functions in angular when using functions in template?

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am using a function inside HTML template, I cannot use a variable directly because the condition is little complex.

My Problem is that the function in the template is called multiple times.

For Example [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaiwhg) **(Minimal, Reproducible Example)**

Logs `get Name was called` 4 times on load and 2 more times after clicking  Change Version button.

I would like to call this once on load and only one per click. How can I achieve that for performance's sake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `changeDetection` mode of the component to `OnPush`

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Using `OnPush` will tell Angular to only render the template when the `@Input()` bindings for the component has changed. The default mode will perform change detection for the template on each digest cycle, and since the expression is using a function it has to call it every time to see if the value has changed.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{getName()}}!</h1>
  <button (click)="changeName()"> this</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit{
   // ....
}
```

Here's a blog on the topic:

https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Comment: I wonder what's the use case of default `ChangeDetectionStrategy`

Comment: @dota2pro backward compatibility for older Angular 2 projects. That's my assumption of why it's still the default. The default was added so that Angular 2 projects would perform change detection in a way similar to Angular 1. A bad decision if you ask me. It should be completely removed from the framework.